# What is the replacement of apache solr with cassandra?

Tags: node.js, solr, cassandra

I have developed Nodejs application which consist of apache solr with cassandra package. We know that cassandra will provide only primary key search, so that apache solr will help out to search for all the fields but in this case apache solr will work only with enterprise package of cassandra, it is not with open source cassandra. Is there any other package like apache solr to support all the field search with open source cassandra database?

Answer (score 1):

Even with the community version you can either use `ElasticSearch` or `Solr` but you have to do the indexing yourself.

But there is one project: **Elassandra**

> Elassandra is a fork of Elasticsearch modified to run as a plugin for
>   Apache Cassandra in a scalable and resilient peer-to-peer
>   architecture. Elasticsearch code is embedded in Cassanda nodes
>   providing advanced search features on Cassandra tables and Cassandra
>   serve as an Elasticsearch data and configuration store.

https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra